# small issue while coverting string value in Date

Tags: java, string, date, datetime, simpledateformat

I am unable to covert String values in The Java.util Date format.

This is my code

```
String string = "24-Nov-2012 14:21:56";
Date soldate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz").parse(string); // problem in this line
System.out.println(soldate);
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you provide details of the exception you get on this line?

Comment: @Will A  No any error my complier simply stops compiling after this line `Date soldate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM....`

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for ideas of how to write a better question in the future.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh: If your compiler "simply stops compiling" then you would have a compiler error message, which you should tell us. If not, how can you tell where it "simply stops compiling"?

Comment: @AshutoshSingh. If you are using an `IDE` like Eclipse, then it will show you a red mark at the place where you are having incorrect syntax. If you hover you rmouse over it, it will tell you what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz")
```

You don't have that `zzz - TimeZone` part in your string. So, your format cannot parse your string. As it is different from the actual string format.

Just remove it: -

```
new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

`SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz")` where `zzz` is the place holder for Timezone part for your date string.

So remove it if your date string is not going to have any timezone information and use this :

`SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")`

See the link below for other options that yu can use with `SimpleDateFormat`

[SimpleDateFormat javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)